# Webpack alternative to RequireJS map config

Tags: webpack

I am currently trying to migrate existing RequireJS project to Webpack and stuck with porting `map` section of my RequireJS config:

```
...
map: {
    // Everyone get an extension module as if it's an original
    "*": {
        "backbone": "backbone_ext",
        "marionette": "marionette_ext"
    },

    // Extension modules get original modules as dependencies
    "backbone_ext": { "backbone": "backbone" },
    "marionette_ext": { "marionette": "marionette" }
}
...
```

From ReqeireJS documentation:

> map: For the given module prefix,
>   instead of loading the module with the given ID, substitute a
>   different module ID.

Is there an alternative in Webpack to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `resolve.alias` that allows to redefine how imports should be resolved.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

This should cover your first issue of aliasing the import of `backbone` to `backbone_ext` whenever it is used, by a rule like:

```
{ backbone: "backbone_ext" }
```

However I assume these resolves are global and I don't really know how to handle the other case for overriding this again when `backbone` should be resolved inside `backbone`. But assuming that inside these modules there are no fully qualified imports (but only relative ones), this could probably already work for you.